# PySide in windows - remove padding from corners

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, pyside

For example if I add QStatusBar to my window, I see too wide corner:

```
self.stat = QtGui.QStatusBar()       
widLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
widLayout.addWidget(some_pannel)
widLayout.addWidget(self.stat)
self.setLayout(widLayout)
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt Stylesheets - how to remove dead space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867987/qt-stylesheets-how-to-remove-dead-space)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867987/qt-stylesheets-how-to-remove-dead-space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QBoxLayout.html#PySide.QtGui.QBoxLayout):

> - **PySide.QtGui.QLayout.setContentsMargins()** sets the width of the outer border on each side of the widget. This is the width of the
>     reserved space along each of the PySide.QtGui.QBoxLayout ‘s four
>     sides.
> - **PySide.QtGui.QBoxLayout.setSpacing()** sets the width between neighboring boxes. (You can use PySide.QtGui.QBoxLayout.addSpacing()
>     to get more space at a particular spot.)

So, basically:

```
widLayout.setSpacing(0)
widLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```